# How to hide a tableView after selecting a row

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, autocomplete

I have a textField, which when touch displays a tableView with some rows.

I'm trying to do this: when a user selects one of the rows, the value of row is placed in the textField and the tableView is closed.

The first part works well for me. The user touch on one row and the textField shows the value of that row. But if I want to close the tableview, I have to press twice on the row.

This is my code:

```
class Redactar_mensaje: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {


    var values = ["123 Main Street", "789 King Street", "456 Queen Street", "99 Apple Street", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple", "owaldo", "ostras", "Apple", "Pineapple", "Orange", "Adidas"]

@IBOutlet weak var campo_para: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var originalCountriesList:[String] = Array()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.isHidden = true


        for country in values {
           originalCountriesList.append(country)
        }

        campo_para.delegate = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        campo_para.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldActive), for: UIControlEvents.touchDown)
        campo_para.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchRecords(_ :)), for: .editingChanged)
    }


    @objc func searchRecords(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.values.removeAll()
        if textField.text?.count != 0 {
            for country in originalCountriesList {
                if let countryToSearch = textField.text{
                    let range = country.lowercased().range(of: countryToSearch, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil)
                    if range != nil {
                        self.values.append(country)
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            for country in originalCountriesList {
                values.append(country)
            }
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return values.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellx")
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cellx")
        }
        cell?.textLabel?.text = values[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        campo_para.text = values[indexPath.row]

        tableView.isHidden = true //I need press twice for this. I want press only one

    }


    func textFieldActive() {
        tableView.isHidden = false
    }

}
```

Ideally, the user touches the textField, displays the tableView, chooses one of the values, and it close automatically the tableView. But this last one does not work well.

Any advice?

Comment: I think you need search functionality. For that use `UISearchBar` or `UISearchController` that will be perfect option for you to match your requirement. In searchbar's delegate method - on searchBarBeginEditing - you can show tableview and on clicking tableview cell, you can hide tableview.

Answer (score 0):

### Details

xCode 8.3, Swift 3.1

### Example to Detect Double tap and Single tap on TableViewCell

> ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as! TableViewCell
        cell.label.text = "\(indexPath)"
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController:TableViewCellDelegate {


    func tableViewCell(singleTapActionDelegatedFrom cell: TableViewCell) {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
        print("singleTap \(String(describing: indexPath)) ")
    }

    func tableViewCell(doubleTapActionDelegatedFrom cell: TableViewCell) {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
        print("doubleTap \(String(describing: indexPath)) ")
        //You can hide your textfield here
    }
}
```

> TableViewCell.swift

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    private var tapCounter = 0
    var delegate: TableViewCellDelegate?


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapAction))
        addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func tapAction() {

        if tapCounter == 0 {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                usleep(250000)
                if self.tapCounter > 1 {
                    self.doubleTapAction()
                } else {
                    self.singleTapAction()
                }
                self.tapCounter = 0
            }
        }
        tapCounter += 1
    }

    func singleTapAction() {
        delegate?.tableViewCell(singleTapActionDelegatedFrom: self)
    }

    func doubleTapAction() {
        delegate?.tableViewCell(doubleTapActionDelegatedFrom: self)
    }
}
```

> TableViewCellDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit

protocol TableViewCellDelegate {
    func tableViewCell(singleTapActionDelegatedFrom cell: TableViewCell)
    func tableViewCell(doubleTapActionDelegatedFrom cell: TableViewCell)
}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I solved it in a much simpler way. Just also the order of the lines and add one more line. First it makes it invisible and then puts the result in the textField and, for some reason, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Here I put my solution, in case someone else would happen something similar.

Just change the order of the lines and add one more line. First it makes it invisible and then puts the result in the textField and, magically, it worked!

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        tableView.isHidden = true
        campo_para.text = NombreUsuario[indexPath.row]
        campo_asunto.becomeFirstResponder()

    }
```

Thanks!